# Registo funcionários externos Validação mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, validação

Quero cadastrar funcionários externos num banco de dados mysql usando o php.

Cada funcionário tem que ter em sua posse uma credencial de acesso onde consta: Empresa, Validade da credencial, validade do seguro contra riscos e aptidão médica para trabalhar.

Estou tentando com as seguintes tabelas: Pessoas, Zonas, Credenciais, Aptidão médica, Seguro e uma tabela registo para calcular quantas horas de trabalho este funcionário trabalhou. (No futuro gostaria de ter um log para saber os dias e horas, mas por enquanto assim chega!)

Este relacionamento que enviei em anexo está correcto ? Ou pode melhorar ?

Muito obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O seu modelo está funcional mas você já pensou em usar `nvarchar` para campos de texto complexo como o de nome? `varchar` guarda uma string de caracteres em 8 bits, enquanto `nvarchar` guarda uma string Unicode, permitindo acentuação e caracteres especiais.

A quantidade de memória gasta com `nvarchar` é maior porém vale a pena gastar alguns bytes a mais pra não se preocupar mais com erros de codificação.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Outra duvida é também os dois tipos de relacionamento com identificação e sem identificação. Neste caso você acha que este sem identificação é o mais adequado ? Obrigado